# Apache If/Else Environment Variable always evaluates true

Tags: apache, if-statement

I have the following environment variable on my server running Apache 2.4 which I have tested apache knows about by doing this.

```
Define envarTest ${MY_ENVAR}
```

then running `apachectl -S` which prints out:

```
Define: envarTest=1
```

As my environment variable is set to `1` this is exactly as I expected. If I change my environment variable to `0` and restart apache, I get a value of `0` as expected too.

On to my problem...

```
<If "'${MY_ENVAR}' == '1'">
 Define SERVICE_IP 192.168.0.1
</If>
<Else>
 Define SERVICE_IP 192.168.0.2
</Else>
```

I therefore expect with my envar set to `1`, the `SERVICE_IP` should be 192.168.0.1, but it is always the latter, `192.168.0.2`, regardless if `MY_ENVAR` is `0` or `1`.

I thought this may be a type operator issue, so I tested `somestring` and it does the same.

I then tried:

```
Define SERVICE_IP 192.168.0.2
<If "'${MY_ENVAR}' == '1'">
 Define SERVICE_IP 192.168.0.1
</If>
```

And regardless what value MY_ENVAR is set to, `SERVICE_IP` is always `192.168.0.1`.

Fearing a complete noob mistake now!! Any ideas?! Thank you.

Comment: This question belongs on [SF], and has already been [asked there](//serverfault.com/q/1073066/16865)